# BIRT report exports to XLSX in design mode but not in Runtime

Tags: javascript, birt, birt-emitter

I am using Birt. Calling it from javascript to run my report at run time.

When I am developing my report everything goes great. When I deploy it and it no longer likes to export to XLSX files.

`http://marquetta:8080/birt/frameset?__report=http://marquetta/reports/userList.rptdesign&__format=XLSX`

all other formats seem to work fine. The above creates an exception:

> "Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
> "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in BIRT 4.5.0 and 4.6.0. Apparently there was a conflict with another version of org.apache.poi which was already included in my project separately. Removing the folder org.apache.poi from the org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar solved the problem.

You may find more information here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398774